# XMLHttpRequest receiving no data or just "undefined"

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

i try to make a Firefox Addon which runs a XMLHttp Request in Javascript. I want to get the data from this request and send it to *.body.innerhtml.

That's my code so far...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://xx.xxxxx.com", true);
xhr.send();
setTimeout(function() { set_body(xhr.responseHtml); }, 6000);
```

Instead of receiving the data, I get "undefined". If I change xhr.responseHtml to responseText I get nothing. I don't know why I'm getting nothing. I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Firefox 12.0.

If you need any more details on the script please ask!

Update:

set_body Function

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
document.body.innerHTML = body;
document.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update SOLVED:

I had to determine the RequestHeaders (right after xhr.open):

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "xxx");
```

For following Items: Host, Origin and Referer. So it seems there was really a problem with the same origin policy.

But now it works! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

when you set the last param of open to true you are asking for an async event. So you need to add a callback to xhr like so:

```
xhr.onReadyStateChange = function(){
   // define what you want to happen when server returns
}
```

that is invoked when the server responds.   To test this without async set the third param to false. Then send() will block and wait there until the response comes back. Setting an arbitrary timeout of 6 seconds is not the right way to handle this.

Comment: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://w69b-groove.appspot.com", true);
xhr.onReadyStateChange = function(){
if (xhr.readystate==4 && xhr.status==200)
{      set_body(xhr.responseText,doc);   
} else
{
alert('Connection didnt work...');
}
} 
xhr.send();`

I changed it but it doesn't work...

Comment: what browser are you in? XMLHttpRequest doesn't work in IE. When you say it "doesn't work" what exactly are you seeing?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm using FF 12.0.

I'm just seeing my "connecting..." Text. It's right before the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: It isn't `onReadyStateChange` but rather `onreadystatechange` - JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    set_body(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.open("GET", "http://xx.xxxxx.com", true);
xhr.send();
```

Make sure that you are getting a correct response from URL http://xx.xxxxx.com. You may have a problem with cross-domain calls. If you have a page at domain http://first.com and you try to do XMLHttpRequest from domain http://second.com, Firefox will fail silently (there will be no error message, no response, nothing). This is a security measure to prevent XSS (Cross-site scripting).

Anyway, if you do XMLHttpRequest from a `chrome://` protocol, it is considered secure and it will work. So make sure you use this code and make the requests from your addon, not from your localhost or something like that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I implemented your solution. But it seems to be that I'm running into the cross-domain error. It just silently leaves on "conecting..." and my network addon doesn't throw any new requests. I'm calling from example.com but I'm requesting from req.example2.com. How can I manage to do a HTTP request from my addon? (As you mentioned 'chrome://')

Regards

Comment: From my experience, the easiest way of doing cross-domain requests, is to create a transparent proxy at your server. For example, every request at http://example.com/ajax/?test=something gets content from http://example2.com/?test=something and returns it without change.

Comment: @pounty: There is no same-origin restriction for Firefox extensions. You should be able to make cross-domain requests just fine unless your code runs in a content script.