# jQuery AJAX beforeSend fails in Firefox browser

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, jquery

I used beforeSend in AJAX jQuery to pass the header value in the REST service.
The header values are passed well in Internet Explorer 8. But the header values are not passed in Firefox and the service is not called.

Here is my code :

```
var postCall = function () {
$.support.cors = true;
var HFAssociateRefId = document.getElementById('MainContent_HFAssociateRefId').value;
var Input = {
     AssociateRefId: HFAssociateRefId
 };       
 alert(JSON.stringify(Input));
 var url = document.URL;
 var currentdate = new Date();
 var datetime = (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
 + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
 + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "
 + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
 + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
 + currentdate.getSeconds();
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       headers: { Accept: "text/plain; charset=utf-8", "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                },
       beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Date", datetime);
       xhr.setRequestHeader("URL", url);
                },
       url: "http://localhost:40680/LinkService.svc/TokenInsertion",
       data: JSON.stringify(Input),
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
       alert(response);
                },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {           
       alert(status);
                },              
});
```

I also tried by calling the xhr as new XMLHttpRequest as specified in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806980/xmlhttprequest-receiving-no-data-or-just-undefined).
But it doesnt work in Firefox. ?? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an alert in `beforeSend function` and test it, Is it working or not?

Comment: @Rohan Kumar yes, the alert value occurs in beforeSend function. But the headers values are not passed.

Comment: If it not works then you can pass `data and url` in `data`

Comment: @Rohan Kumar If I pass the value through data, then I need to add an extra columns in my table.

Comment: In firefox the `Date` header is not working, but it is sending `URL`, can you confirm this?

Comment: @kk1076 If you agree with @Arun then you should try your code by changing the key variable from `Date` to `dateString`.

Comment: @Arun Its not sending URL also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the  [link](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers). Firefox and Chrome never accepts new custom headers to be added as it violates the browser security rule.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Firefox is not respecting the header `Date`. It is sending the header `URL`. I'm not able to find any resource to explain this behaviour.

As a solution you can rename the header `Date` to something else.

Chrome also shows the same behaviour.

On further investigation, it looks like the standard behaviour as per the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest). Look under the section titled `Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:`

The same was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973403/chrome-extension-refuse-header-date-in-ajax-request).

Comment: I changed the date variable into a string. But still it passes the header value.

Comment: @kk1076 it passes or not passing

Comment: is it sending the ajax request? if yes can you share the headers from using the browser's dev toolbar

Comment: In Firefox, the ajax request doesnt calls the service. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

the fist problem this is:

```
type: "post",
data: JSON.stringify(Input), <=== this is fail
correct is: data:{data:JSON.stringify(Input)}, 
recuest to $_POST['data']; is better if using arrays...
```

I recommend you try with jquery ... this example is very easy.

Basic sample!

Page 1 to Html or PHP not is very important this name...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Prueba Array 1</title>
**<!-- important download JQUERY 1.3 or late... -->**
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function toSend(d) {
        $.ajax({  
            type: "get", **// this is posible chain by "post"**
            url: 'test.php', 
            data: {datos:JSON.stringify(d)},  
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(test) { 
                //console.log("visualizacion del registro Name[1]: "+ test.names[1])
                console.info("Array Send");

                $.each( test, function( key, value ) {
                      console.log( key + ": " + value );
                      });
            }
        });


    }

    // send Submit
            $(":send").live('click',function(){
                                    console.log("preparing to send! ");              
                            // lista de entradas en un ID
                            var data    =   $('#form_1 input').serializeArray();
                        // Serializacion de las entradas input
    //                  // Acciones
                    toSend(data);

                    });


    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="ie">
    <form id="form_1" action="#" >
    <input name="Nombre" type="text" value="Petronila">
    <input name="Apellido" type="text" value="Sinforosa">
    <input name="Telefono" type="text" value="phone">
    <input name="Ciudad" type="text" value="Living in Caracas">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

to the next, Copy this code and then save it as test.php! and run

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['datos'])){
$names  = array('john doe', 'JANE doe');
$ids    = array('123', $datos);

$data['names'] = $names;
$data['ids'] = $ids;


    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    $error  =   array('error','No se recibieron metodos');
    $error  =   array('messeng','Method need chain test to Get');
    echo json_encode($error);
}
?>
```

ok is very, very important to check the results in the browser console F12 to check any of these, you need to activate the console firefox sometimes
im test and is ok!

Comment: Using  data:{data:JSON.stringify(Input)} throws a Bad request in both IE8 and Firefox